Supermodels randomly being murdered in slasher-movie ways
This isn't going to be easy, but its worth a shot. I remember watching it on TV in the 90's, specifically 94-95 timeline. 
The movie was about these supermodels on location that were randomly being murdered, like in slasher-movie ways. One had a jet-ski sabotaged, one had a car that was driven off a cliff, and one was poisoned with water from her canteen. But the shock twist ending is that all the models had faked their deaths the entire time to get back at the guy who was attempting to kill them...or something along those lines. 
I'm pretty sure it aired on a major network in primetime. Can anyone identify this movie?

Might be "The Cover Girl Murders" from 1993.

This struck a cord with me. I'm a big Highlander nerd, and so watched a few Adrian Paul movies back in the day. He's in The Cover Girl Murders. It's USA network so I guess "major network" is a matter of opinion. :P But I found it on YouTube (I dunno if it's okay to link, so no link) and peeked to make sure:
Jet Ski death, at about the 31:30 mark.
Poison drinking water about 54:15
Car off the cliff about 64:20
Ladies aren't actually dead at about 81:35
